# How to create index with new fields, parsing values from field in existing index?

Tags: elasticsearch, reindex

I have an index that contains 1 document. This document has a field1 with value "B" and a field2 with value "C, D, E" (that is, the value in field2 is comma separated and can have variable lenght).
I want to create a new index, that contains the following 3 documents:
field1: "B" and field2:"C"
field1:"B" and field2:"D"
field1:"B" and fielde:"E"
I was thinking about using a watcher to reindex the already existing documents and creating the new field at the same time. But I'm not sure how to do this nor if this is the correct approach.

Comment: Is the field2 always have 3 comma-seperated values?

Comment: It might have any number of comma-separared values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to do this with a version of the following python script:

```
import logging
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch, helpers
import schedule
import time
import sys

# Configure logging to save logs in parse.log file
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO, filename='parse.log', filemode='a', format='%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

# Configure Elasticsearch connection
es = Elasticsearch(hosts=["https://elasticsearch.com:111"], basic_auth=("elasticsearch_user", "elasticsearch_password"))

# Define source and destination index names
source_index = "source_index"
dest_index = "dest_index"

# Optional query to filter documents from source index
query = {
    "size": 5000,  # Adjust the size based on your requirements
    "query": {
        "range": {
            "@timestamp": {
                "gte": "now-1d/d",
                "lte": "now/d"
            }
        }
    }
}

# Use the helpers.bulk API for efficient indexing
def job():
    actions = []
    for hit in es.search(index=source_index, body=query)["hits"]["hits"]:
        # Modify document if needed before adding to actions
        source = hit["_source"]

        # Extract value of fields field1 and field2    
        field1 = source["field1"]
        field2 = source["field2"]
        
        # Extract specific terminals
        field1_string = str(field1)
        field2_string = str(field2)
        nodes = field2_string.split(",")

        # Define de id of the document, according to the number of terminals
        if len(nodes) == 0:
            source["node"] = ""
            actions.append({
                "_index": dest_index,
                "_id": hit["_id"],
                "_source": source.copy()  # Create a copy of the source dictionary
            })
        else:
            for node in nodes:
                new_id = field1_string + node
                source_copy = source.copy()  # Create a copy of the source dictionary
                source_copy['host'] = node
                actions.append({
                    "_index": dest_index,
                    "_id": new_id,
                    "_source": source_copy
                })

    # Send all the documents to the destination index using bulk API
    try:
        helpers.bulk(es, actions)
        logger.info(f"Bulk indexing successful. Processed {len(actions)} documents.")
    except Exception as e:
        logger.error(f"Error during bulk indexing: {e}")

def main():
    # Schedule the job to run every day at 7 am
    schedule.every().day.at("07:00").do(job)

    try:
        # Run the scheduler in an infinite loop
        while True:
            schedule.run_pending()
            time.sleep(1)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        # Handle Keyboard Interrupt (Ctrl+C)
        logger.info("Received KeyboardInterrupt. Exiting gracefully.")
        sys.exit(0)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ingest pipeline](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/ingest.html) with [script processors](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/script-processor.html).

##### add dummy data

```
POST _bulk
{"index":{"_index":"source_index","_id":"1"}}
{"field1": "B", "field2": "C,D,E,F,G"}
```

##### create the ingest pipeline

```
PUT _ingest/pipeline/split-pipeline
{
  "description": "Split values in field2 dynamically",
  "processors": [
    {
      "split": {
        "field": "field2",
        "separator": ","
      }
    },
    {
      "script": {
        "source": """
          for (int i = 0; i < ctx.field2.size(); i++) {
            ctx["field2_" + i] = ctx.field2[i];
          }
        """
      }
    },
    {
      "remove": {
        "field": "field2"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

##### reindex the data

```
POST _reindex
{
  "source": {
    "index": "source_index"
  },
  "dest": {
    "index": "destination_index",
    "pipeline": "split-pipeline"
  }
}
```

##### search the new data

```
GET destination_index/_search
```

##### OUTPUT:

```
"hits": [
  {
    "_index": "your_destination_index",
    "_id": "1",
    "_score": 1,
    "_source": {
      "field1": "B",
      "field2_4": "G",
      "field2_3": "F",
      "field2_2": "E",
      "field2_1": "D",
      "field2_0": "C"
    }
  }
]
```

> Note: For real time data flow you can add the ingest pipeline
> into your source_index settings.

```
PUT source_index/_settings
{
  "index.default_pipeline": "split-pipeline"
}
```

> For the existing data you can use `_update_by_query` API call.

```
POST source_index/_update_by_query?pipeline=split-pipeline
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you Musab Dogan. That's helpfull and works as described. But I was hoping to generate more that one document in the destination-index, if field2 (in the source-index) has more than one comma separated value. For instance, if I have a document in the source index with field1: A AND field2:B,C, in the destination-index I should get two documents: document 1 has field1: A AND field2:B and document2 has field1: A and field2:C.

Comment: You're welcome gbs, thanks for clarifying. You can't do that directly in elasticsearch. Need to create a script with python or similar tool. First, It should calculate all fields, 2. documents should be gathered and index one by one. You can get help from chatGPT to do that.

Comment: Perfect. Thank you for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: You're welcome please let me know the results.

Comment: I managed to get what I wanted with a python script, as you suggested (see above).

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, happy to hear you make it work.